# Send messages using Facebook API iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, messaging, facebook-ios-sdk

I was wondering if it is possible to send direct Facebook messages from one user to another using Facebook's API on iOS. If not is there any work arounds, could I get permission from Facebook.

Thanks in advance.

Ben.

Comment: with the new [change Log of](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog) Facebook now you need to submit facebook app reivew for publish permission.

Answer (score 0):

```
        str_id = [[app.Arr_Facebook_Frnd objectAtIndex:indexpath] objectForKey:@"id"];
        str_name = [[app.Arr_Facebook_Frnd objectAtIndex:indexpath] objectForKey:@"name"];
        str_link = @"www.google.com";

NSDictionary *params = @{
                             @"name" : str_name,
                             @"caption" : @"",
                             @"description" : @"",
                             @"picture" : @"",
                             @"link" : str_link,
                             @"to":str_id,
                             };


    // Invoke the dialog
    [FBWebDialogs presentFeedDialogModallyWithSession:nil
                                           parameters:params
                                              handler:
     ^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {
         if (error) {
             NSLog(@"Error publishing story.");
             [self.indicator stopAnimating];
         } else {
             if (result == FBWebDialogResultDialogNotCompleted) {
                 NSLog(@"User canceled story publishing.");
                 [self.indicator stopAnimating];
             } else {
                 NSLog(@"Story published.");
                 [self.indicator stopAnimating];
             }
         }}];
    [self.indicator stopAnimating];
```

Comment: its for post message, on friend's wall